# identify if the list has a number <10 and all 0 after that

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

To check if the input list of numbers is ending with more than one 0s, the last non-zero value must be less than 50.

There can be scenarios like the following:

```
[500,5000,600,1212,234232,121,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

should return `True` (ending with 0s and 10 is smaller than 50)

```
[500,5000,600,1212,234232,121,500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

should return `False` (ending with 0s, but 500 is not less than 50)

```
[500,5000,600,1212,234232,121,200,0,0,0,0,0,0,50]
```

should return `False` (there is 0 at the end)

Comment: So, does the code you have written manage to pass any of these test cases?

Comment: How many zeros qualify as "few"?

Comment: So find the last non-zero value. Check if it's less than 50 and that it's not the last element.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a service for people too lazy to do their homework. Read [tour] and [ask].

Comment: `A[max(i*(n>0) for i,n in enumerate(A))] < 50 and not A[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> f = lambda x: len(x) > 1 and x[-1] == 0 and (lambda z: len(z)>0 and z[-1]<50)([y for y in x if y!=0])
>>> f([500,5000,600,1212,234232,121,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
True
>>> f([500,5000,600,1212,234232,121,500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
False
>>> f([500,5000,600,1212,234232,121,200,0,0,0,0,0,0,50])
False
>>> f([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
False
>>> f([])
False
>>> f([0])
False
```

Comment: good catch. I updated the lambda to fix this